# Not able to create a plan using dj-stripe from django admin

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am using `dj-stripe==1.0.0.post1`. I have followed the installation steps as mentioned [here](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

When I go to the django admin and try to create a plan,  I get this error

`KeyError at /admin/djstripe/plan/add/  'stripe_id'`

here is the full stack trace:

```
ERROR 2017-09-27 11:07:57,600 django.request Internal Server Error: 
/admin/djstripe/plan/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        
    packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,     
    **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 551, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in 
    _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 224, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1508, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1408, in 
    changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, 
    extra_context)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1448, in 
    _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/djstripe/admin.py", line 298, in save_model
    Plan.get_or_create(**form.cleaned_data)
  File "/Users/swapnil/Work/li-django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-
    packages/djstripe/models.py", line 939, in get_or_create
    return Plan.objects.get(stripe_id=kwargs['stripe_id']), False
  KeyError: 'stripe_id'
```

What am I missing here. I have configured all the things mentioned in the installation guide

Comment: please post your view

Comment: There is not view related to stripe yet. I am just trying to create a plan from the DJANGO ADMIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not supposed to add the plans from the admin screen. `djstripe` expects you to create the plans in stripe and let the webhook create the plans in your database.

And of course you will have to use something like `ngrok` so that you can let stripe make the API calls to a publically accessible IP